# Beamer block - problem with it's appearance

Tags: beamer, xetex

I made a beamer presentation with desktop that looks like...
[image]

And when I open it from mobile phone, it looks like...
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=white,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=gray!30}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=gray!90}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=purple}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray!20}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=purple}        
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\shadowcolor{black}
\shadowoffset{0.8pt}
\shadowtext{%
\color{purple}Random frame
}%
}
\begin{block}{\centering 
\shadowcolor{black}
\shadowoffset{0.8pt}
\shadowtext{%
Random block
}%
}
Random text
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know what i have to change?

Comment: Can you try with a different pdf viewer? Maybe your viewer has a problem with transparency?

Comment: If the transparency is the problem, you could try with a theme which uses blocks with sharp corners, e.g. `\usetheme{Luebeck}`. Or try with `\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}` to replace the normal beamer blocks with tcolorboxes.